# Eclipse: Content Assist not available within a handler

Tags: java, eclipse

My Code Assist (Ctrl Space) works in Eclipse but not everywhere. If I type

Thread. inside the onClick handler, no proposals are listed. They will appear if I type them outside of this handler. Why?

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
  @Override
   public void onClick(View v)
   {
     Thread.sleep(100);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My bet is that it is an [IDE bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=367612) that causes the content assistant to fail in the anonymous class.

Comment: Strangely, it only does it in one project. If I try it in another project it works.

Comment: @AndroidDev Maybe you can strip down the problem a little bit by distinguishing between the contexts in two projects. For example, does that happen in anonymous class as well? Does that happen in overridden method?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code in eclipse and everything was fine and the code **Thread.**  actually opened the eclipse *intellisense*.

Your problem might be due to one of the following:

1. Some errors exist in the overall java file
2. Something wrong in the added external/internal libraries
3. Something's stuck in eclipse background-operations

In either the way a removal and re-addition of the used libraries will solve the problem;
Then restart eclipse.